# Can two consecutive の particles be used in the following way?

Tags: grammar, syntax

We can use `の` as a substitute in successive sentences for something we've already mentioned so that we don't need to keep saying what it is:

> - どのTシャツが好き？　→　赤い**の**が好き。

Then there is the possessive/associative の:

> - 家の屋根、空の鳥、etc.

I was telling my friend about a new wallet I bought.  By implication (or obviousness), it means the wallet I had before is now the "old wallet".  So I wanted to talk about the contents of the old wallet.  Can I use these two `の`s consecutively to describe them, like:

> - 古いの　の　中身

Is this grammatical?  Used?  Or would it be better to just say `古い｛財布・もの・やつ｝の中身`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first の is the *pronoun* の.
The second の is the *genitive* の.

There are two possible sequences of these two のs:

> 1. *genitive + pronoun:*　 この本は花子の<strike>の</strike>だ。 "This book is Hanako's."
> 2. *pronoun + genitive:*　 赤いのの表紙　"the cover of the red one"

In the former, the sequence of two のs is ungrammatical; you have to delete one of them.
In the latter, the sequence of two のs is okay.

(Examples adapted from [a draft version of Hiraiwa's *Constraining Doubling*](http://www.meijigakuin.ac.jp/%7Ehiraiwa/PDF/Hiraiwa_Identity_Draft09292012.pdf), although there are a number of publications on this subject--see the references section of the linked paper for further discussion.)

Comment: Can you say この本は花子のんだ though?

Comment: Hiraiwa says ***some*** speakers use んの or のん, in which case deletion doesn't occur.  I take this to mean that you should avoid the のん version in standard Japanese, though the paper doesn't say so explicitly.

Comment: ~のん sounds childlike to me. (幼稚園児か、小学校低学年くらいの・・・でも、近年はあまり聞かない気がする・・・古い言い方なのかも)

Comment: @Chocolate ええこと言わはるわ。むっちゃ懐かしい響きや。確かに最近聞かへんな。

Comment: @TokyoNagoyaさんは東京と名古屋火傷、関西弁なん？

Comment: @istrasci その「[火傷]{やけど}」は変換ミス？ それともギャグ？

Comment: @Chocolate: ギャグやで！